# OrgChart with photos

Tags: templates

I was wondering if anybody might have a template for an org chart with photos. I'm looking for a good draft to make a chart containing 5 people. it should show less about structure but more about the individuals.

Comment: A table for the photos (and description) with `tikz` nodes that show the structure?

Comment: I was thinking of a box for every single person with a photo and his position and some additional information about what his responsibilities are.

Comment: Have a look on `tcolorbox` for nice boxes etc.

Comment: Is there any news here?